# Error in myf(3) : argument "coef" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, r-markdown, roxygen2

I keep getting this error when I try to call my function in the .rmd file I am working in. I have tried looking up how to resolve this issue, but nothing has worked. The function I am working with is very simple and I am working in the same project the function is saved in.

This is my function:

```
#' Double Function
#'
#' @param x
#'
#' @return Multiplies vector by 2
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' x = 1:30; myf(x)
myf = function(x){
  x*2
}
```

and I am calling it like this in my .rmd file:

```
library(MATH4753)
myf(1)
```

I receive this error every time:

```
Error in myf(1) : argument "coef" is missing, with no default
```

I would like to understand why this is happening and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The package, MATH4753, contains a function called myf(), looks like your code is running this rather than the locally defined function.

You could change the name of your function, say my_f().